# SaltStack: Module file.find iname parameter

Tags: salt-stack

i try to use Saltstack to deploy part of our applications.

I would like to delete all zip files in a directory with the module file.find
so i write this formulas:

```
  remove_ZIP:
    module.run:
      - name: file.find
      - path: {{ custom_dir }}/
      - args: 
        - delete
        - iname: \*zip
```

With this all files are deleted.

I try to use kwargs to declare iname constraints with the error

```
'kwargs' must be a dict.
```

Could someone help me to understund how to use this module?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message says, you should use `kwargs` with a dict instead.

```
remove_ZIP:
    module.run:
      - name: file.find
      - path: {{ custom_dir }}
      - kwargs: 
          delete: f
          iname: "*.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks you @blhsing,

so my problem was just an indentation problem...

Indentation with 2 spaces before 'delete' is in error and succeeded with 4 spaces